# Adding a persistent bar at the top of Gmail using an extension with activations

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I am using a Chrome Extension to inject a js file which adds a bar at the top of Gmail, and everything worked great until recently, when I started having problems with its persistence. I guess Google changed something about Gmail's behavior.

The js file adds a div element to the beginning of the body tag, and so I get the bar at the top of the page, and everything else shrinks a bit to accommodate for it. 
The problem is that as soon as the user clicks anything, Gmail stretches to take up the whole vertical space and pushes the bar up outside of the visible area. The div is still present in the DOM, but is no longer visible.

Any suggestions on how to make that bar more persistent?